# GSON library error with Lotus Notes Java Agent - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.JsonObject

Tags: java, json, gson, lotus-domino, javaagents

I am trying to use GSON library to convert Java object to JSON in a Java Agent in my Lotus Notes application. I have added GSON jar file to Project->Java Build Path. But when I run the agent, I am getting error - "Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.JsonObject".

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to get some JSON from external API and then save it in Lotus Notes database. I am able to send HTTP request, but what I am getting in return is a Java object. I want to convert it to JSON.

Here's the class file to,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class CustRestConsumer {
    /**
     * Method for receiving HTTP JSON GET request against a RESTful URL data source.
     * 
     * @param myUrlStr the URL of the REST endpoint
     * @return JsonObject containing the data from the REST response.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     * @throws ParseException 
     */
    public static JsonObject GetMyRestData( String myUrlStr ) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        JsonObject myRestData = new JsonObject();
        try{

            UrlValidator defaultValidator = new UrlValidator();
            if(defaultValidator.isValid(myUrlStr)){

                URL myUrl = new URL(myUrlStr);
                URLConnection urlCon = myUrl.openConnection();
                urlCon.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                InputStream is = urlCon.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isR = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isR);
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                myRestData = (JsonObject) parser.parse(buffer.toString());

                return myRestData;

            }else{
                myRestData.addProperty("error", "URL failed validation by Apache Commmons URL Validator");
                return myRestData;
            }
        }catch( MalformedURLException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            myRestData.addProperty("error", e.toString());
            return myRestData;
        }catch( IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            myRestData.addProperty("error", e.toString());
            return myRestData;
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the function here,

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import lotus.domino.*;




public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

          // (Your code goes here)
          Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();

          String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
          System.out.println("Reached Here - 1");
          JsonObject myStuff = CustRestConsumer.GetMyRestData(url);
          System.out.println("Reached Here - 2");
          System.out.println(myStuff);

          Document newNotesDoc = db.createDocument();
          newNotesDoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "IBMForm");
//          newNotesDoc.replaceItemValue("WebPageUS", dto.title);
          newNotesDoc.computeWithForm(true, false);
          newNotesDoc.save(true, true);

          db.recycle();

      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

This is the Java debug console output,

```
Reached Here - 1
Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.JsonObject
    at CustRestConsumer.GetMyRestData(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject
    at lotus.domino.AgentLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
```

I am new to Java agents, so any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Project->Java Build Path is for using JAR files in XPages. I believe the jar file can be added directly to the agent or a script library, but there are memory leak issues with detaching them, so it's not recommended. The recommended approach is to add them to the jvm\lib\ext of the server and, presumably, also the client that is trying to compile the code.

There are other options for scheduling Java code in Domino, some of which are covered here https://www.intec.co.uk/tag/xots-microservice-scheduler-tutorial/, but there are other imaginative approaches possible.